# how to load data in hive automatically

Tags: hadoop, load, hive

recently I want to load the log files into hive tables, I want a tool which can read data from a certain directory and load them into hive automatically. This directory may include lots of subdirectories, for example, the certain directory is '/log' and the subdirectories are '/log/20130115','/log/20130116','/log/201301017'. Is there some ETL tools which can achieve the function that:once the new data is stored in the certain directory, the tool can detect this data automatically and load them into hive table. Is there such tools, do I have to write script by myself?

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do this using Hive external tables and partitioning your table by day. For example, create your table as such:

```
create external table mytable(...) 
partitioned by (day string) 
location '/user/hive/warehouse/mytable';
```

This will essentially create an empty table in the metastore and make it point to `/user/hive/warehouse/mytable`.

Then you can load your data in this directory with the format **key=value** where **key** is your partition name (here "day") and value is the value of your partition. For example:

```
hadoop fs -put /log/20130115 /user/hive/warehouse/mytable/day=20130115
```

Once your data is loaded there, it is in the HDFS directory, but the Hive metastore doesn't know yet that it belongs to the table, so you can add it this way:

```
alter table mytable add partition(day='20130115');
```

And you should be good to go, the metastore will be updated with your new partition, and you can now query your table on this partition.

This should be trivial to script, you can create a cron job running once a day that will do these command in order and find the partition to load with the `date` command, for example continuously doing this command:

```
hadoop fs -test /log/`date +%Y%m%d`
```

and checking if `$?` is equal to 0 will tell you if the file is here and if it is, you can transfer it and add the partition as described above.

Comment: thanks a lot, in fact, i have a further question, by this way i can load my log files divided by date into hive tables, however, my boss asked me to find a approach or tool
to load data,that means:assuming there is a certain directory called '/log',the hive will query this directory all the time,once the new data is produced,maybe /log/20130118,/log/20130119,the hive will add this partition automaticly and load the log file such as /20130118 or /20130119 to the partition of table, how can i achieve that,beg your pardon

Comment: When you specify the keyword `EXTERNAL` your data isn't copied anywhere and stays in the location you putted it. (When you don't specify `EXTERNAL`, Hive copies the data to its own default location). As far as I know, every time you add a file to the folder specified by `LOCATION` and you query your table afterwards, the new data should be visible. It's been a while since I played with Hive, so maybe @Charles Menguy can confirm this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure i understand what you want to achieve, can you edit your question with more details? If you just want to flat load files into your table without date partitions, then @Pieterjan is right, you can just put the files at the root of your table in HDFS and you don't need to alter the table, Hive will directly pick it up.

Comment: my goal is load the data automaticlly,the flow may be like this
Firstly,the hive will detect whether new log file exists.if yes,
the hive will create a new hdfs directory,for example'/exercise3/20131118' and load the new log file into it.Then it creates a new partition for the new log file.since I will analyse the data from telecommunication equipment.so the data is large.i have to load it automaticlly.i think the engineer from facebook will choose to load the large amount of web data automaticlly rather than load them manually.beg your pardon.thanks a lot @Charles Menguy

Comment: @jackyzhang I added more details in my answer, you can just use the `hadoop fs -test` and the `date` commands to do this very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of LOAD DATA command provided by Hive. It exactly matches your use case. Specify a directory in your local file system and make Hive tables from it.

Example usage - 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/user/some-directory'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE table